# Scala: reading lines from file with curried function in 'foreach'?

Tags: scala, foreach, partial-application

Reading lines from file I try to use curried function in 'foreach' :

```
import scala.io.Source
object CurriedTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    fun("one")("two")("three")
    (fun2)("three")
    val lst = List ("x", "y", "z")
    lst.foreach(fun2) 
    lst.foreach(fun("000")("111") ) 
    Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines.foreach(fun("AAA")("BBB") _)    
    Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines.foreach(fun2)
  }

  def fun (a1: String) (a2:String) (a3: String) = {
    println("a1: "+a1+" a2: "+a2+" a3: "+a3)
  }

  def fun2 = fun("one")("two") _
}
```

For some reason neither of the following statements:

```
    Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines.foreach(fun("AAA")("BBB") _)    
    Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines.foreach(fun2)
```

produce any output. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was reading an empty file which naturally produced an empty output. Sorry for the confusion.